# Python: vertex normal according to World

Tags: python

If i get a normal of a vertex - i'll get it in local coordinates.
For example:

```
bpy.context.object.data.vertices[0].normal
```

If an object will have rotation or scale - normal direction will be incorrect according to world orientation. How to convert the vertex normal according to the world?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it is, when the scaling factors are not the same (as @mifth pointed out) :

```
normal_local = C.object.data.vertices[0].normal.to_4d()
normal_local.w = 0
normal_local = (C.object.matrix_world @ normal_local).to_3d()
```

If you know they are all the same, you can use :

```
C.object.rotation_euler.to_matrix() @ C.object.data.vertices[0].normal
```

Cheers,

Comment: yes, that's corect. the only problem - if object is scaled non-proportionaly (like (0.1, 0.5, 0.7)) it will make incorrect normal direction too.

Comment: It takes rotation but it does not take scale now. Possibly there should be adifferent solution. :( Sorry.

Comment: The solution above gives the normal the correct direction. I don't understand how you want the scale to be taken into account for the normal. Maybe you can scale the normal by the mean of the 3 scale factors, would that be what you want ?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Here is what i want to say http://i.imgur.com/WPpUp5B.png If scale will be different - normals will have different direction.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't thinking about this case. I updated the answer, it should suit your needs :)

Comment: Thank you a lot Jonathan!!! I fixed my issue with the normal now.
Here is my fix for the MifthTools and MiraTools https://github.com/mifth/mifthtools/commit/9497e0db54adc01a5126d443eaeb3fccd7db2c7b

I had to change your formula to get correct result with inverted matrix and a quaternion applied to it. The corrected formula looks like this now http://pastebin.com/csm2e5HF
In this way any scaled/rotated object give us correct normal.

Comment: Or it looks like this in your style http://pastebin.com/AJQwMiiG

Answer (score 10):

**Normal Matrix.**

***EDIT**. Original answer did not allow for non-uniform scale. Have added a script to reinforce the answer of [@patmo141_](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61250/15543)*

Create a normal matrix

$$n' = (M^{-1})^{T} \cdot n $$

as in script below

```
mw = ob.matrix_world
N = mw.inverted_safe().transposed().to_3x3()
```

[image]

Test script, adds a single arrow type empty at each face normal aligned with face normals in global space.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

norm_length = 2

context = bpy.context
bpy.data.batch_remove((o for o in context.scene.objects if o.type == 'EMPTY'))

ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world
N = mw.inverted_safe().transposed().to_3x3()

for f in ob.data.polygons:
    n = N @ f.normal
    mt = bpy.data.objects.new("n{f.index}", None)
    mt.location = mw @ f.center
    mt.rotation_euler =  n.to_track_quat().to_euler()
    mt.empty_display_type = 'SINGLE_ARROW'
    mt.empty_display_size = norm_length
    context.collection.objects.link(mt)
```

Note, using face normals as example, for vertex normals as per question

```
for v in ob.data.vertices:
    n = N @ v.normal
    mt = bpy.data.objects.new("n{f.index}", None)
    mt.location = mw @ v.co
```

**Without inverting.**

Using the technique outlined in [Stop Using Normal Matrix](https://lxjk.github.io/2017/10/01/Stop-Using-Normal-Matrix.html)

\begin{align*}
\vec{N'}&=\frac{N_0}{a}\vec{X} + \frac{N_1}{b}\vec{Y} + \frac{N_2}{c}\vec{Z}\\
&=(\frac{N_0}{a}, \frac{N_1}{b}, \frac{N_2}{c})M
\end{align*}

Test script,

- Get the scale vector vector `s`
- Normalize the rotation part Matrix `M`
- There's an issue where negative scale flipping result
- make a vector `n`  from normal by dividing each component by scale component
- post multiply by `M` to obtain result normal

edit to above: (remembering to import `Vector` from `mathutils`)

```
M = mw.to_3x3().normalized() 
s = mw.to_scale()
for f in ob.data.polygons:
    n = f.normal
    n = Vector((n.x / s.x, n.y / s.y, n.z / s.z)) 
    
    n = n @ M
```

**Zero scale component.**

Both these methods will have issues when any scale component is zero. The use of `inverted_safe` will avert risk of divide by zero error at cost of result accuracy. Will look into this.

**From the bmesh directly.**

As noted in answer to [link] could also apply the transform to a bmesh and update its normals. Tnen the face normals of the bmesh the calculated normals. (The mesh is not updated or written back to)

[image]
*Empties added at world coords to mimic  normals of evaluated mesh*

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy import context
norm_length = 2

bpy.ops.object.mode_set()
bpy.data.batch_remove((o for o in context.scene.objects if o.type == 'EMPTY'))

ob = context.object
dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_object(ob, dg)
bm.transform(ob.matrix_world)
bm.normal_update()
for f in bm.faces:
    n = f.normal
    mt = bpy.data.objects.new("n{f.index}", None)
    mt.location = f.calc_center_median()
    mt.rotation_euler =  n.to_track_quat().to_euler()
    mt.empty_display_type = 'SINGLE_ARROW'
    mt.empty_display_size = norm_length
    context.collection.objects.link(mt)
    
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

Comment: Do you think we should already answer Python questions assuming Blender 2.80? It is still not released, would it not make sense to assume people do not yet use it for work?

Comment: It's quite _ad hoc_ This one came up from another question, needed an edit, so I updated for 2.8, rather than wait for a _more sensible moment in time_

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. I was just wondering how to approach this when answering other questions. I'll probably start including comments for changes in 2.80 with answers for 2.79.

Comment: ... still trying to get my head round what the transpose is doing.... :(

Comment: @RobinBetts ditto link from "don't invert"  link in answer http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-12-tutorial/the-normal-matrix/  Any ideas re dealing with normal flipping with negative scales?

Answer (score 6):

I've run into this problem many times, I always have to search for the answer. But I use the tranpose of the inverse of the world_matrix to get the world normal.

https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/why-is-the-transposed-inverse-of-the-model-view-matrix-used-to-transform-the-nor

```
mx_inv = C.object.matrix_world.inverted()
mx_norm = mx_inv.transposed().to_3x3()

world_no = mx_norm @ C.object.data.vertices[0].normal
```

Answer (score 4):

you have to multiply it with the world matrix (the order matters! Matrix first) :

`C.object.matrix_world @ C.object.data.vertices[0].normal`

Comment: Shouldn't the matrix be first in the multiplication?

Comment: @natille not sure how the math goes here, you can edit the post if you think it's wrong.