# Delete face(s) along axis with python

Tags: python, scripting, faces

I'm trying to delete, as in [This Example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36933/efficient-way-to-delete-all-points-below-z-0-on-grid-via-python-script), but **Faces** instead of vertices along a particular axis. So, as an example (see image) this cube's face that I have selected would need to be deleted along the x axis using python. From the above link (following mostly the 3rd answer), I don't understand how they're setting which axis to delete by, or how to do the operation for faces.

[image: Cube with left face select]

My code is is different, because my needs are different than the example. It doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't do anything

```
    def _debug(vert):
    n_selected = len([v for v in vert if v.select])
    n_deselect = len([v for v in vert if not v.select])
    print('\nlen vertices = {}, {} selected, {} not selected'.format(
            len(vert), n_selected, n_deselect))
       
    
    x_thresh=0.0        
    vert = bpy.context.object.data.vertices
    _debug(vert)
    for v in vert:
        if v.co[2] < x_thresh:
            v.select = True
    _debug(vert)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='VERT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`bmesh` version**

If choosing answers from that question would recommend editing the [answer of @CoDEmanX](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36980/15543)

Test script, removes all faces which have all vertices with an x coordinate less than zero.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.object
assert ob.type == "MESH"
mat = ob.matrix_world
me = ob.data


if me.is_editmode:
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
else:
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(me)

bmesh.ops.delete(
        bm,
        geom=[f for f in bm.faces if all(
                v.co.x < 1e-6 for v in f.verts)
            ],
        context='FACES'
        )


if bm.is_wrapped:
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
else:
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    me.update()
```

To remove faces with a normal pointing in the -X direction

```
bmesh.ops.delete(
        bm,
        geom=[f for f in bm.faces if f.normal.angle((-1, 0, 0)) < 1e-6
            ],
        context='FACES'
        )
```

Comment: Not working on my end. Am I missing some aspect?

Comment: Please inform of the result you get running above on default cube in either object or edit mode. If you are running it on a mesh that has no faces with all vertices x coordinate > 0 then nothing will appear to happen. (Hope this is not the case) Have edited and added a tolerance to remove verts that are tolerance zero but slightly positive which could result in some faces not being removed on the meridian of the default sphere (for example). If this is what you mean by not working, please, in future expand further.  If it still doesn't work can add a gif showing it working at my end.

Comment: Works. Please describe in detail what *exactly* does not work @Increality

Comment: Thank you. Adding the Remove faces with normal pointing in the -X direction got it working. I was only using it on the cube from my image, not a sphere, but this will be good to know. I assumed it was something I was doing on my end. Thank you for the help @batFINGER