# How can I access the values set via normals_split_custom_set()?

Tags: python

I use a [variety](https://www.blend4web.com/), [of](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/normal_edit.html), [methods](https://www.blend4web.com/) to set the loop normals but want to read them to do some raycasting.

I *thought* I had to call `calc_normals_split()` then match up vertices via their vertex_index.  However the result I get seems off from that shown by entering mesh edit mode and turning on `show_normal_loop` ("Display vertex-per-face normals as lines").

Here're are the results with colour names in top right describing each:

[image: Image showing results]

I want to get the magenta one which is produced by Blender itself.

Red and yellow are the untransformed and transformed **point** normals.  The yellow ones correctly line-up with the blender-displayed point normals when turned on.  That implies I'm using the correct matrix for transforming them from local to world (I used the inverse transpose technique explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27491/python-vertex-normal-according-to-world/61250#61250) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)#Transforming_normals)).

The black and cyan are the untransformed and transformed loop normals.  Obviously they aren't near the magenta ones.

And finally a code excerpt.  Obviously I'm using the GreasePencil API to do the drawing.

```
def getFirstLinkedLoopForVertex(objData, v):
    for l in objData.loops:
        if l.vertex_index == v.index:
            return l

def getMatrixForNormals(obj):
    return obj.matrix_world.inverted().transposed().to_3x3()

normalMatrix = getMatrixForNormals(raysSource)
raysSource.data.calc_normals_split()
 # TODO: Restore retro-normalized() -- non-uniform scale messes it up.
for l in [(p.co * raysSource.matrix_world, p.co * raysSource.matrix_world + (getFirstLinkedLoopForVertex(raysSource.data, p).normal * normalMatrix) * 0.2) for p in pointsToRaycast]:
    debugDrawLine(l, Color((0, 1, 1)), "loop * normalsMatrix = broken?") # cyan = loop * normalsMatrix = good?
```

Any help appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

p.s. If I don't issue `calc_normals_split()` then the loop normals are all zero.  Since I now suspect they're not the normals I'm looking for, I guess it's no value but I thought it'd be good to mention.