# Objcet has no mesh data to be used for ray casting

Tags: python, scripting

When I try to do a `ray_cast` in object mode, I get an error “Object has no mesh data to be used for ray casting”
I tried to fix it with following the steps:

```
bpy.context.scene.update()
context.active_object.data.update()
context.active_object.data.update(calc_edges=False)
context.active_object.update_tag(refresh={‘OBJECT’, ‘DATA’, ‘TIME’})
```

And even:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=‘EDIT’)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=‘OBJECT’)
```

Code
[Line 208](https://github.com/Darcvizer/Destructive-Extrude/blob/master/Destructive-Extrude.py)

Comment: I think this is a currently bug or oversight. Fails with same error in console `C.object.raycast(v, d)` The template operator raycast exhibits this behaviour too. (once fixed for missing dupli in 2.8)  Re your script, not sure about the logic re `mw.inverted() * f.normal.`  Suggest converting to global space, and then to local space of the object you are raycasting from. [global normal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27491/python-vertex-normal-according-to-world)

Comment: Thank you very much. Regarding logic, you are right, thanks!

Comment: unfortunately at the moment blender2.8 gives the same behaviour for the closest_point_on_mesh method.