# How to get "true" face normal in scaled object?

Tags: python, mesh, transforms, normals

I work on addon for UV box mapping. In my addon I need to check face normal to sort X,Y or Z oriented faces. [By following this topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/how-to-convert-coordinates-from-vertex-to-world-space) I found how to compensate object rotation by multiplying object matrix to face normal vector.

Now issue with object scale. On image - object scaled by Z to 0.1, face normal look almost straight to up to Z but mesh data still return normal as if object not scaled.

Question is - how to compensate object scale to get "true" face normals? Blender do it somehow under the hood when showing Normal Gizmo for selected face so how can I get same result.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger) for help.

```
import bpy, bmesh, mathutils

bmd = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.edit_object.data)

nrm = bmd.select_history.active.normal      #Pick normal for active element.
obm = bpy.context.object.matrix_world       #Get object world matrix.

nrm_fixed = (obm.inverted_safe().transposed().to_3x3() @ nrm).normalized()
```

Comment: I take it the quest here is to find the global space normal. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27491/python-vertex-normal-according-to-world  Edited a test script into my answer to add an empty as a "global normal" display. Couldn't get a result using  `nrm_fixed` as above.

Comment: Formula I have posted only compensate object scale. If object has also rotation u need first compensate scale then rotation by multiply result with `matrix_world.to_3x3().normalized()` ( .to_3x3() - removed location 
 .normalized() - removed scale) Not sure I get it right *"I take it the quest here is to find the global space normal."* I have checked your link... so u propose just use `mw.inverted_safe().transposed().to_3x3()`? [Check this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/n5OkpVM.png) - my final vector look at (1.0000, 0.0009, 0.0006), your one at (0.8581, -0.3095, -0.4098) what looks wrong.

Comment: Now it become interesting for me - on your GIF empties looks placed perfectly correct along the normals. I not sure but it looks like because you don't use `.normalized()` (so you get actually scaled normal vector) this `n.to_track_quat().to_euler()` you use to set empties rotation take in to account that normal scale and set correct euler rotation. Interestingly... But still not work for me - I need clear normalized and correct face normal vector for my addon purpose.

Comment: OMG - I just realized that `(object.matrix_world.inverted_safe().transposed().to_3x3() @ normal).normalized()` return same (1.0000, 0.0009, 0.0006) normal vector. Thank you kindly for your help ))